# OnClick of Servlet > Need to Fetch the Data of Particular Person from Database and Display it on JSP

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp, jdbc

Java -Code 
Here I have 8 Subscribers in my database and its been displayed on frontend as a table format (Columns -User name, type of Subscriber, date, validity Till)
Click on the Subscriber user name > it has to fetch that particular name and his validity details. This has to be done using JAVA.
Here I have used Servlet Counter, So onclick the Count has been increased every time and the count has been passed as the parameter to my Model Class which accepts the count has parameter and the data from the database have been stored in ArrayList. Using ArrayList getInt method the Count has been passed into this.
The Application is Working Fine! but when the application reaches more visitors and the servlet count is not initialized back to **hitCount** to Zero. How to fetch the data dynamically way in java? and what I can improve in this code to get a proper result!

**ServletCounter**

```
private int hitCount; 

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session=request.getSession();
        hitCount++
        try {
            Model m=new Model();

            System.out.println("Entering getstatement method...");
            String NAME=m.getStatement(hitCount);

                session.setAttribute("NAME", NAME);
                response.sendRedirect("ManageAccount.jsp");
                System.out.println(NAME);
            }


        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
```

**Model Class**

```
public class Model{

public String getStatement(int hitCount) throws Exception 

    {

       System.out.println("Inside getStatement..");
        pst = conn
                .prepareStatement("SELECT user FROM trillup.subscribers");
       ArrayList ar=new ArrayList();

        rs = pst.executeQuery();


        ar.add("");
        while(rs.next()==true) 
        {
           System.out.println("Inside while loop");
            ar.add(rs.getString("user"));
        }

            System.out.println(ar);

        hitCount++;
        String NAME=(String) ar.get(hitCount);
        return NAME;



    }  
}
```

Comment: You can add limited value for `hitCounter` and once it reaches to the limit you can re-initialized it to `0` .Also why don't you store `hitCounter` value in session ? ..Your servlet is always increasing `hitCounter` value ? Why don't you get value from session and then perform operation on that value ?

Comment: Thank you for Your Response!! The database is not static it keeps growing and my table too on the front end! So I cant keep the hitCounter on the limit!  Anything I can do? What I'm facing is the hitCounter is coming back to zero

Comment: Please, Someone, Help Me regarding this, @Swati I tried Your Suggestion but the count is not re-initializing to zero. Anything more do you have? it would be a great help.

Comment: At what condition you need to re-intialize your value ? You said in you question `n reaches more visitors...` but how much ?

Comment: Based on no of data on my database -For Example, There are 10 names on the database, and those ten names are stored in ArrayList, so the limit is 10 now and for 11th click on servlet the count has to re-initialize to zero and again the loop has to repeat. - the value of count!! I'm passing that value to -ArrayList ar= new ArrayList(); - ar.getInt(count); Hope you Got it! Thanks in advance. @Swati

Comment: .  Put `ArrayList` in session , so that everytime a new clicked come you can use `ar.size()` and check this against your `db` value (no of users) and if the value is more re-initialize the count .

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to initialize the hitCount = 0 before the DoGet method?
Take a look at the sql JSTL library manual. It is very interesting and easy to use in fetching data. Doesn't need any mastery of data structures

Comment: Yes! I have initialized to zero at the beginning only! Thank you I will look into SQL JSTL

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to maintain the hitcount counter increase every time there is request for subscribers.

Don't keep the count in Main memory, if the jvm crash? You ll lose the data, so maintain this counter in table level.

Edit - have your counter re- initialized on any dynamic value ( probably read from some configuration) and have logic re- initialized to zero in the table.

And also try to have model class neatly defined.

```
Class Model{
Private List<Subscriber> subscribers;
// getter setter
}

class Subscriber {
Long hitcount ;
//Rest attributes

}
```